# Switch statement not responding to changes

Tags: swiftui

I got the following switch statement:

```
@State private var selectedTestament = Testament.all
    
enum Testament: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case all
    case vt
    case nt
    var id: String { self.rawValue }
}
   
let filter: Testament
var filteredTestament: [Book] {
        
    switch filter {
    case .all:
        print("all")
        return bookViewModel.books
    case .nt:
        print("nt")
        return bookViewModel.books.filter { $0.testament == "NT" }
    case .vt:
        print("vt")
        return bookViewModel.books.filter { $0.testament == "VT" }
    }
}
```

And the following picker

```
Picker("Testament", selection: $selectedTestament) {
    Text("Both").tag(Testament.all)
    Text("VT").tag(Testament.vt)
    Text("NT").tag(Testament.nt)
}
.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
Text(
```

No matter if I click "Both", "VT", or "NT", I only see the the message from `print("all")` printed in the console.
`Text("Testament: \(selectedTestament.rawValue)")` on the other hand updates correctly and displays the correct text, but why is only "all" printed to the console and not "nt" / "vt" when toggling the picker?

`filteredTestament` is used here:

```
ForEach(filteredTestament) { book in
  NavigationLink(
    destination: ChapterView(book: book),
    label: {
      HStack {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {  
          Text(book.name)
          Text(book.author)
          Text("\(book.chapters) chapters")
        }
      }
    })
}
})
}
.onAppear {
  self.bookViewModel.fetchBooks()
}
```

Comment: Where is your code that calls `filteredTestaments`? Thanks

Comment: In a list below - but thats irrelevant for now - I can't get the switch case statement to work.
`ForEach(filteredTestaments) {...}`

Comment: It's not irrelevant. Your `print` statement is inside a function that isn't being called in the code you have displayed. :D

Comment: At the moment you have a binding to `selectedTestament`. You then have text that shows `selectedTestament` which is updating correctly. But In your switch you're not using the `selectedTestament` to switch on anything. You're using `filter`. But `filter` is not being updated in your code anywhere. Can you show the code that is updating the `filter` value? Thanks

Comment: I updated the code to show the ForEach part

Comment: I want the picker itself to call the switch statement so the ForEach can update accordingly

Comment: What happens if you just delete the `filter` property and use the `selectedTestament` inside the switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have added an extra property without actually needing it.

Your picker is updating `selectedTestament` but your switch is using `filter` which is never actually update.

If you remove `filter` you should be able to do...

```
@State private var selectedTestament = Testament.all

var filteredTestament: [Book] {
    switch selectedTestament {
    case .all:
        print("all")
        return bookViewModel.books
    case .nt:
        print("nt")
        return bookViewModel.books.filter { $0.testament == "NT" }
    case .vt:
        print("vt")
        return bookViewModel.books.filter { $0.testament == "VT" }
    }
}
```

Comment: That actually does work - thanks. Why is `filter` messing it up? I assumed I needed some form of computed property

Comment: `filter` isn't strictly messing it up. It's just not being updated. You have a property that is being updated by your `picker` but then you're ignoring it and using something else to actually filter the array. Your `Text` was updating because it was using the `selectedTestament` property and so when the picker changed it it got a new value. You just added in a superfluous value that wasn't being involved with the picker updates. But in fact... you just didn't need it at all. :D